# Jquery: Show related div when you click and hide others

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 divs with different content. I want to show the related div when I click on the link. It's showing both divs at the moment and it was supposed to show only the related one.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/g25hsdw6/)**

```
$('div.tip-2').hide(); 

$('.showDiv').on('click', function() {
    $('div.tip-2').fadeIn(200);
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('div.tip-2 *')) {
        $("div.tip-2").fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="showDiv" href="#">Show div</a>
<div class="tip-2">
<p>This is one!</p>
</div>

<br/><br/>
<a class="showDiv" href="#">Show div</a>
<div class="tip-2">
<p>This is two!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('div.tip-2').hide(); 

$('.showDiv').on('click', function() {
    $("div.tip-2").hide();
    $(this).next().fadeIn(200);
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('div.tip-2 *')) {
        $("div.tip-2").fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

**[updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g25hsdw6/3/)**

Comment: I know I should post a new question but it's not allowing me. What if I use select2.js plugin? I want to show the div when I click inside the select and hide it when I click outside. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/jEADR/1713/

Comment: Amazing! I just changed to focusin() instead but it's working. Thank you very much!

Comment: @brunodd Glad to help youuuu

Answer (score 2):

Make the script understand its relation. Change it to:

```
$('div.tip-2').hide(); 

$('.showDiv').on('click', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $('div.tip-2').fadeOut(200, function () {
        $this.next('div.tip-2').fadeIn(200);
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('div.tip-2 *')) {
        $("div.tip-2").fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/g25hsdw6/4/

Comment: Is it possible to hide any visible div?

Comment: @brunodd Yes, but your question is not clear. This is scalable. Works for 100s of divs too!

Comment: I edited the question, should make more sense now. Your code is nearly there. How I can hide other divs?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
    $('div.tip-2').hide(); 

    $('.showDiv').on('click', function() {
       $("div.tip-2").hide();
       $(this).next('.tip-2').fadeIn(200);
       event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('div.tip-2 *')) {
            $("div.tip-2").fadeOut(200);
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/g25hsdw6/5/